# cant access php uploaded on go daddy server

Tags: php, android

i have created an android app which fetch data from the database,on localhost the php is working fine.i can test the php file  also..but its aint working with godaddy server i have uploaded all the php files there in appphp folder.but when i want to test that php file through browser its shoeing following error..:-

`The requested URL /politiciansnpolitics/politiciansnpolitics/appphp/parties.php was not found on this server`.

Additionally, a `404 Not Found` error was encountered while trying to use an `ErrorDocument` to handle the request.

Apache Server at www.politiciansnpolitics.in Port 80  "

its working fine in localhost..how to work with godaddy server..sorry this is the first app am using server ..that why

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
http://www.politiciansnpolitics.in/appphp/parties.php
```

Remove the extra `/politiciansnpolitics/politiciansnpolitics/`

Test the link I gave you it is accessible.

Comment: now its showing following error:-Failed to connect to the database: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: actually i have uploaded my apphp folder inside politiciansnpolitics folder

Comment: Well that is not a `404` though which you were having before. Now this error regards with your coding.

Comment: no error in coding php is working fine in go daddy .its just i cant able to access that php when i uploaded on server